# Change a back color that exists in a different form

Tags: c#

Hello I'm trying to change a square color pnlPlayer in PlayingField.cs however the choice must exist on ColorChoice.cs

Whenever I try to change the pnlPlayer.BackColor to a different color the pnlPlayer tells me it does not exist in the current context.

how can I change the backColor of pnlPlayer that exists in PlayingField from ColorChoice

Here is the relevant code.

ColorChoice.cs

```
 private void ColorChoice_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //set colors to combobox
     //ComboBox ColorComboBox = new ComboBox();
     ColorComboBox.Items.Add("Red");
     ColorComboBox.Items.Add("Blue");
     ColorComboBox.Items.Add("Green");
     ColorComboBox.Items.Add("Black");

     //add to combobox form
     this.Controls.Add(ColorComboBox);
 }

public void ColorConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlayingField PF = new PlayingField();
    PF.Show();
    switch (ColorComboBox.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 1:
            pnlPlayer.BackColor = Color.Red; //The problems are here
            break;
        case 2:
            pnlPlayer.BackColor = Color.Blue; //The problems are here
            break;
        case 3:
            pnlPlayer.BackColor = Color.Green; //The problems are here
            break;
        case 4:
            pnlPlayer.BackColor = Color.Black; //The problems are here
            break;

    }
```

PlayingField.cs

```
public PlayingField()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        StartGame();
}

public void StartGame()
{
    pnlPlayer.Location = new Point(200, 200);
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.J || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) //LEFT
    {
        int newX = (pnlPlayer.Location.X - 10 >= 0) ? pnlPlayer.Location.X - 10 : 0;
        pnlPlayer.Location = new Point(newX, pnlPlayer.Location.Y);
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.I || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) //UP
    {
        int newY = (pnlPlayer.Location.Y - 10 >= 0) ? pnlPlayer.Location.Y - 10 : 0;
        pnlPlayer.Location = new Point(pnlPlayer.Location.X, newY);
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.L || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) //RIGHT
    {
        int newX = (pnlPlayer.Location.X + 10 <= 400) ? pnlPlayer.Location.X + 10 : 400;
        pnlPlayer.Location = new Point(newX, pnlPlayer.Location.Y);
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.K || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) //DOWN
    {
        int newY = (pnlPlayer.Location.Y + 10 <= 400) ? pnlPlayer.Location.Y + 10 : 400;
        pnlPlayer.Location = new Point(pnlPlayer.Location.X, newY);
    }
    else return;    //user pressed a key that does not have a function in the program

}
```

Comment: Obviously, there is no `pnlPlayer` defined in the posted code. I can only guess that it exist in the `PlayingField` object `PF`, and if `pnlPlayer` is `public`, then `PF.pnlPlayer.Backcolor…` should work.

Comment: What technology/UI framework are you using - WinForms, Unity, WPF, ....?